# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en_US

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-1.2

I am new to JSF an was trying out this piece of code.. This is my faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
```

messages is a file that stores a few properties and messages file is not  placed under any directory, it is placed directly under the application. Why cant i access this file?
Thank you in advance.. please do let me know if you need any additional information..

Comment: put the file at `/WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: Is your file is called `messages.properties`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like your file placed in some package inside your `src` folder

```
<base-name>some.package.name.Messages</base-name>
```

also make sure the file called `Messages.properties`

b.t.w are you aware that `Messages.properties` file will allow you to override your validators error messages?

Also, take a look at this nice tutorial [JSF 2 message and messages example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-message-and-messages-example/)

Comment: thanks.. hadn't placed the file under src.. but now i did.. inside a nice package structure. named the file Message.properties. Also i need to write **package.Messages** and not **package.messages**.. inside the faces-config.xml.. the 'M' matters. Writing it in details for some other helpless newbie like me out there

Comment: You are welcome, I know about the `M` , it was a left over of copy/paste of your question :)

Comment: cool.. not a problem.. was looking into your question.. Will have to learn about validators before i learn its influence.. Will be back with more questions later

Answer (score 3):

If you put it in directly into src folder it should work. Athough I would suggest to organize the message files in packages.