# JSF Local config not working

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, locale

I've configured `Locale` before in JSF applications, but for some reason I keep getting the following:

> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name 
>   com.cleanup.bundle.messages, locale es

## faces-config.xml

```
<application>

    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>com.cleanup.bundle.messages</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>

    <locale-config> 
        <default-locale>es</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>

</application>
```

The `.properties` files:

[image: project]

For some reason I just can't make it work, please don't mark as duplicate since I've already verified with these:

1. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328418/java-util-missingresourceexception-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-resources-ap)
2. [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927032/java-util-missingresourceexception-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-messages-lo)
3. [also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986234/cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-bundle-locale-en-us)
4. [etc ...](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-xxx-locale-en_us/)

My configuration is exactly the same as I've used in the past but.. nothing works, I even tried to set the local to the default locale:

```
<f:view locale="#{languageBean.locale}">
```

With a bean like so:

```
@Named(value = "languageBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LanguageBean implements Serializable {

    private Locale locale;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getDefaultLocale();
    }
```

And for some reason getting the same `MissingResourceException`.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try to remove `com.cleanup.` and see if it's working ???

Comment: @YagamiLight, I tried that  already :/

Comment: I'm not familiar with Netbeans, but I see that you're using Maven. Isn't there a src/main/resources folder? You should be putting resources there in Maven projects. Perhaps it's the "Other Sources" as Netbeans calls it? See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540907/maven-and-jsf-webapp-structure-where-exactly-to-put-jsf-resources

Comment: You can always try the concept of debugging and see what is actually going on. Setting a breakpoint in the class that according to the stacktrace throws the exception should not be that difficult. Very easy to do an very educational

Comment: Have you added that faces-confing in web.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select "Files" tab instead, and put the files in the folder

src -> main -> resources (create it if it's not there).

Back on the projects tab, they should turn up under

"Other sources" -> src/main/resources -> default package.

Files tab:

[image]

Projects tab:

[image]

I'd also remove the package name (or to say, I haven't tried with that).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your war file. It can be that the maven build is not putting your properties file at the desired location as it picks up the properties from resources folder, so try putting the package structure in resources folder and build again .The maven folder structure is 
src ---main 
        |-java
        |-resources
        |- webapp